# Python math adding numbers from two list index by index

Tags: python, list, math

I am still a beginner in Python. I am trying to implement an algorithm that involves vector and normalised difference between the vector. The equation is given as

```
Sr = 1 - ( || r1 - r2|| / || r1 + r2|| )

A given example gives r1 and r2 as shown below. 

r1 = {1 2 3 4 5 6 0 3 3 0 0 0 1 1}
r2 = {4 0 3 0 0 0 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9}

Sr = 0.2023
```

A breakdown of the formula would look something like this.

```
r1-r2 is the subtracting the item1 in r1 to the item1 in r2, subtracting the item2 in r1 to item2 in r2,..., until item-n in r1 and r2.

Let's say M is the total sum of (r1-r2)
M = sum(r1-r2) = sum[(1-4) + (2-0) +...+(1-9)]

||r1 - r2|| = math.sqrt(x)(math.(M, 2))
```

Basically I can do all the other math related functions but I am having problems finding an efficient way to calculate M where I need to add/subtract numbers from two list index by index. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `zip`?

Comment: It's hard to say how to improve the code you written without seeing the code you've tried. However, it sounds like you should be using numpy- numpy arrays can be added or subtracted (or many other operations) and it performs the operation element by element.

Comment: @David Robinson - I just need to find a way to add/subtract the elements from two list element by element first... I have never used numpy. I will look into that. Thanks.

Comment: This line appears to be invalid syntax: "`math.sqrt(x)(math.(M, 2))`". What are you trying to do here?

Comment: @Asad - Actually I just wanted to show how the algorithm would look like because I cannot seem to use symbols here. It should be sqrt((r1-r2)^2).

Comment: @Cryssie That would be `abs(r1-r2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`numpy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/) can simplify your life:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> r1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1])
>>> r2 = np.array([4, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> 1 - np.linalg.norm(r1-r2) / np.linalg.norm(r1+r2)
0.20227596478253429
```

Your question does not state clearly which norm you need. But the answer seems right, which means that you need the regular 2-norm. Also see [`numpy.linalg.norm`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html)

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is the most elegant one but it's risky for me as I do not truly understand numpy and the codes you provided. I will have to look in the link you gave me so that I can be sure that I got the equation right.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
>>> r1 = [1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,0 ,3 ,3 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,1]
>>> r2 = [4 ,0 ,3 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,5, 6 ,7 ,8 ,9]
>>> [r1[i]-r2[i] for i in range(0,len(r1))]
[-3, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, -1, 1, 0, -5, -6, -7, -7, -8]
>>> [r1[i]+r2[i] for i in range(0,len(r1))]
[5, 2, 6, 4, 5, 6, 1, 5, 6, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> r1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
>>> r2 = [4, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> sum([x-y for x, y in zip(r1, r2)])
-19
```

Explanation:

- zip returns a list of tuples in the form `[(r1[0], r2[0]),...,(r1[n], r2[n])]`
- the list comprehension will perform the `r1[n]-r2[n]` and return the list of results

Answer (score 0):

For sum simply do

```
map(sum, zip(r1, r2))
```

and for difference you can do

```
map(lambda t: t[0] - t[1] ,zip(r1, r2))
```

where `r1` and `r2` are lists.

Answer (score 0):

To do the `sum` part of your math problem you can do the following:

```
sum(map(operator.__sub__, r1, r2))
```

This will perform a subtraction between the elements or `r1` and `r2`, and then sum the resultant list.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who answered. If I can vote for all of you, I would. I decided to pick Reinier Torenbeek's answer because it does everything I want to do for this equation in one simple function.

This is how I used the equation for this part.

```
def wordOrderSim(list1, list2):
    r1 = np.array(list1)
    r2 = np.array(list2)
    Sr = 1 - np.linalg.norm(r1-r2) / np.linalg.norm(r1+r2)
    return Sr

r1 = [1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,0 ,3 ,3 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,1]
r2 = [4 ,0 ,3 ,0 ,0 ,0 ,1 ,2 ,3 ,5, 6 ,7 ,8 ,9]

print wordOrderSim(r1, r2)
```

Thanks to Serdalis, Sushant Gupta, Sheng and Paulo Scardine for your answers as it did answer my question but I forgot to mention that after adding/subtracting the numbers from r1 and r2, each of those numbers have to be in power of two of the original numbers before adding all of them together. Sorry, it's been hard for me to explain them without the proper math symbols.

```
r1-r2 = [-3, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, -1, 1, 0, -5, -6, -7, -7, -8]
sum(r1-r2) = [(-3^2) + (2^2) + (0^2) + (4^2) + (5^2) + (6^2) + (-1^2) + (1^2) + (0^2) + (-5^2 + (-6^2) + (-7^2) + (-7^2) + (-8^2)]
```